# Is it possible to see "hidden" documents without knowing they exist?

Tags: web

is it possible to see all files that are theoretically viewable by a link but not linked on the main website?

For example:
Let's say the website has:

```
index.html
undepage/index.html
supersecretdocument.pdf
```

Is it possible to see the supersecretdocument.pdf know that the document exists without knowing that it's there?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking "Can I know a file exists without trying to GET (or HEAD) it?", the answer is "no."